# Rails: translate ActiveRecord error template headers for a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, authlogic, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to rename the authlogic error messages in a Rails 3 app.

The general format I found out working in Rails 3:

```
de:
  errors:
    template:
      header:
        one:    "Konnte {{model}} nicht speichern: ein Fehler."
        other:  "Konnte {{model}} nicht speichern: {{count}} Fehler."
      body: "Bitte überprüfen Sie die folgenden Felder:
```

But I want to change this for the authlogic user session model (and only for this one) because when the Login fails, the message "Could not save user session" does not make very much sense.

How can I do that?

Comment: Bad news, but rails3 removed the helper's that made use of these error messages in rails2. They are available in a plugin, but chances are that the error messages you are looking to change are hard coded or configurable somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I fixed it this way:
Put in your view (like: **_form.html.erb**)

```
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= I18n.t('activerecord.errors.template.header', :count => @user.errors.size, :model => @user.class) %></h2>
  <h4><%= I18n.t('activerecord.errors.template.body', :count => @user.errors.size) %></h4>
```

It should work fine!